# How to convert document to a custom object in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to convert the document retrieved from the Firebase's Cloud Firestore to a custom object in Swift 5. I'm following the documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

However, Xcode shows me the error `Value of type 'NSObject' has no member 'data'` for the line `try $0.data(as: JStoreUser.self)`. I've defined the struct as `Codable`.

The code:

```swift
func getJStoreUserFromDB() {
    db = Firestore.firestore()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    db.collection("users").document((user?.email)!).getDocument() { 
        (document, error) in
        let result = Result {
            try document.flatMap {
                try $0.data(as: JStoreUser.self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The user struct:

```swift
public struct JStoreUser: Codable {
    let fullName: String
    let whatsApp: Bool
    let phoneNumber: String
    let email: String
    let creationDate: Date?
}
```

The screenshot:

[image: The screenshot]

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Just init the custom object with the dictionary returned by Firestore

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing in the `.getDocument()` completion handler, but I think you need to convert the `Data` returned into a dictionary via `guard let json = let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: document.data(), options: []) as? [String:[String:Any]]`, or something along those lines (your data may not be structured as `[String:[String:Any]]`). From there, you can grab the individual values and initialize an object form those values. As bsod mentioned, you could also pass a dictionary in the initializer and initialize an object that way as well.

Comment: Wait, I'm seeing which part of the documentation you are replicating. I use realtime database, and have no issues converting the `Data` returned from the request into a dictionary via `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`. So long as the request is returning JSON data, you should be able to convert it into an object via this method.

Comment: It would help to understand what you're trying to do here - what does the Firestore structure you're reading look like and what is JStoreUser class? Are you attempting to take data from a Firestore Document and make a Swift Struct from it? Note this `$0.data` is a dictionary <String, Any>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After contacting the firebase team, I found the solution I was looking for. It turns out I have to do `import FirebaseFirestoreSwift` explicitly instead of just doing `import Firebase`. The error will disappear after this. (And of course you'll need to add the pod to your podfile first:D)

Comment: Does it work? As I'm not getting the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` in import autocomplete

Comment: Yes, you'll need to add `pod FirebaseFirestoreSwift` first. Then you can import:D

Comment: Can you please share me the GitHub repo for the above mentioned pods

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment

Comment: Glad I helped:D

Comment: I imported the FirebaseFirestoreSwift in libraries using package manager without pod of my project.
But error appeared yet. Could you explain about that?

Comment: Do you have `pod FirebaseFirestoreSwift` in your Podfile? And did you run `pod install`? @DevSolution

Comment: I imported FirebaseFirestoreSwiftbeta using package manager without pod.
so I fixed it using snapshotlistener.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as shown below:-

First create model class:-

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase

//#Mark:- Users model
struct CommentResponseModel {

    var createdAt : Date?
    var commentDescription : String?
    var documentId : String?

    var dictionary : [String:Any] {
        return [
                "createdAt": createdAt  ?? "",
                "commentDescription": commentDescription  ?? ""
        ]
    }

   init(snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
        documentId = snapshot.documentID
        var snapshotValue = snapshot.data()
        createdAt = snapshotValue["createdAt"] as? Date
        commentDescription = snapshotValue["commentDescription"] as? String
    }
}
```

Then you can convert firestore document into custom object as shown below:-

```
func getJStoreUserFromDB() {
    db = Firestore.firestore()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    db.collection("users").document((user?.email)!).getDocument() { (document, error) in
        //        Convert firestore document your custom object
        let commentItem = CommentResponseModel(snapshot: document)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I was looking for a way to use the `Codable` protocol and convert the document to an object directly (like in Java, one can use `document.toObject(User.class)`.) The Firebase documentation shows something similar, but it's not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your struct and then you can extend the QueryDocumentSnapshot and QuerySnapshot like:

```
extension QueryDocumentSnapshot {
    func toObject<T: Decodable>() throws -> T {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data(), options: [])
        let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
        
        return object
    }
}

extension QuerySnapshot {
    
    func toObject<T: Decodable>() throws -> [T] {
        let objects: [T] = try documents.map({ try $0.toObject() })
        return objects
    }
}
```

Then, try to call the Firestore db by:

```
db.collection("users").document((user?.email)!).getDocument() { (document, error) in
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let commentItem: [CommentResponseModel] = try? document.toObject() else { return }
     // then continue with your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I had some issues though importing FirebaseFirestore with the package manager in my project.
So I explain about the access to FirebaseFirestore in swift.

1. SnapshotListener

   ```
    import Foundation
    import FirebaseFirestore

    class BooksViewModel: ObservableObject {
      @Published var books = [Book]()

      private var db = Firestore.firestore()

      func fetchData() {
        db.collection("books").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
          guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
          }

      self.books = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Book in
        let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
        let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
        let author = data["author"] as? String ?? ""
        let numberOfPages = data["pages"] as? Int ?? 0

        return Book(id: .init(), title: title, author: author, numberOfPages: numberOfPages)
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. using uid and getDocument function

   ```
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        self.errorMessage = "Failed to fetch current user: \(error)"
                        print("Failed to fetch current user:", error)
                        return
                    }

                    guard let data = snapshot?.data() else {
                        self.errorMessage = "No data found"
                        return

                    }
            let uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
            let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
            let profileImageUrl = data["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
            self.chatUser = ChatUser(uid: uid, email: email, profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl)
    }
   ```