# Swift Cloud Firestore Custom Object Mapping

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relatively new with Firebase's new Cloud Firestore and I'm having difficulty trying to map data to/from. I've tried following documentation via Google online, but it has some issues I cannot figure out the origin of.

1. When I try to cast from `[String : Any]` to my custom struct, the documentation suggested I try the following:

```
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            let result = Result {
                try document.flatMap {
                    try $0.data(as: City.self)
                }
            }
            switch result {
            case .success(let city):
                if let city = city {
                    print("City: \(city)")
                } else {
                    print("Document does not exist")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

However, this produced an error on the line `$0.data(as: City.self)` with *Value of type 'NSObject' has no member 'data'*.

2. When I try to write data as a Document to a new collection, the documentation suggests I try the following:

```
do {
    try db.collection("cities").document("LA").setData(from: city)
} catch let error {
    print("Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
}
```

But this also produces an error on the `.setData(from: city)` with *Argument labels '(from:)' do not match any available overloads*.

Does anyone have any familiarity with this to try to provide additional clarity for casting Firestore data to custom structs? I understand my structs are intended to be codable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are having the same issue I had a few days ago: [Firebase (Cloud Firestore) - How to convert document to a custom object in Swift 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548819/firebase-cloud-firestore-how-to-convert-document-to-a-custom-object-in-swift)

The key here is to do `import FirebaseFirestoreSwift` explicitly instead of just doing `import Firestore`.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! Thank you! I wish the documentation mentioned this more specifically as it says it's optional in the podfile example.

Comment: You are welcome:D I was also puzzled by this until I got the reply from the Firebase team. I've already suggested that they add this explicitly:)

Comment: My dude, thank you! This is the solution. Top man. Anyone looking at this, make sure to add pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift' to your podfile as well.

Comment: Haha. No problem. I was actually really struggling a lot. And I'm glad this helped:D

Answer (score 0):

Never found reasoning for the errors but...

1. I ended up converting `$0.data` to a JSON Data object and then decoded as such appropriately in order to map the dictionary to the struct.
2. [How can I use Swift’s Codable to encode into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209743/how-can-i-use-swift-s-codable-to-encode-into-a-dictionary)