# How to convert firestore cloud document to a complex custom object in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed my iOS app and I have a question about using firebase.

I've already read this question.

[How to convert document to a custom object in Swift 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548819/how-to-convert-document-to-a-custom-object-in-swift-5)

However, I have a different question.

I've got document data from firebase cloud store.
and I've been trying convert the data to my custom object.

Here is my object.

```
struct Car: Codable{
var car_id : String
var user_id : String
var alias : String
var car_number : String
var trip_summary : [String : Any]
var create_time : Date
var update_time : Date
}
```

My problem is how to map trip_summary to my custom object.

I made subclass for my trip_summary.

```
class Trip_Summary: Codable {
    var total_distance: Int
    var total_time: CLong
    var avg_mileage: Float
    var avg_score: Float
    var last_trip_id: String
    var last_trip_distance: Int
    var last_trip_time: CLong
    var last_fuel_mileage: Float
    var last_driving_score: Int
    var best_mileage: Float
    var best_score: Int
}
```

But I couldn't convert trip_summary.

What I've tried.

1. We created a decodable object and declared it instead of Any type.

- There was no detail on how to do this, so I tried it and gave up.

2. Declared and converted to TripSummary format.

- This causes the document to return nil.

3. Just change everything to string and declare one by one.

- This is not a good programming method.

Here is my firebase

[Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7HsW.png)

[Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu0cT.png)

Please understand that I cannot disclose all codes due to security issues.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you try again after setting the `Float` values to `0.0` instead of `0` in Firestore?